# Unity 2d Game dont show 3d text

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text

Recently I tried to get 3D text into my scene into my 2D game..The strange thing is that text appear normally on my other projects , only on this one text doesn't appear ... I really don't know why this is happening . 
¸This is my photo of text into scene without any other objects.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9f25z.png)

And when i click to play the scene it doesn't show up 
Here is scren play 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwh25.png)

And this is my Camera settings maybe there is some problem ..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eMNM.png)

Strange thing is that when i do the same in some other project it shows up normally .. I really can not find solution online and this is my only chance to get it done and working if someone know what the problem is here.

Thank you so much for reading my question and I will wait for some solutions..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your camera's z position is `-10` and its "near" clipping plane is `0.3` so anything with a z position less than `-9.7` won't be rendered by that camera.  Your `New Text` object's z position is `-9.9`.  Set it to `0`.